# Meaning of this XPath expression

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am new to XML and XSLT programming.
Can anybody explain the meaning of below XPath expression?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Order[Header/string-length(ORDERID) > 0]/Header/SAP_WBSELEMENT[not(. = following::SAP_WBSELEMENT)]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning**: *Select `SAP_WBSELEMENT` elements, including those with duplicate string values only once, that are children of `Header` elements that are children of any `Order` elements in the document with a `Header` child with an `ORDERID` with an non-empty string value.*

---

**Breakdown**: Working from the end of the XPath back to the front...

*Select `SAP_WBSELEMENT` elements, excluding those with duplicate string values,*

```
SAP_WBSELEMENT[not(. = following::SAP_WBSELEMENT)]
```

*that are children of `Header` elements,*

```
Header/
```

*that are children of those `Order` elements with a `Header` child with an `ORDERID` with an non-empty string value,*

```
Order[Header/string-length(ORDERID) > 0]/
```

*anywhere in the document,*

```
//
```

Comment: I would add the advice that `[not(. = following::SAP_WBSELEMENT)]` is likely to be very inefficient compared with other ways of eliminating duplicates, unless the source document is very small indeed.